# Add IF / CASE statement inside where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Dont know whether we can add if or case inside where condition .

I am trying to convert a  dynamic query in to simple query

```
Declare @sQuery varchar(20000)
set @sQuery=''

set @sQuery ='select * from #tb_user ud'

if(@Number<>'')
set @sQuery = @sQuery + 'and upper(ud.ID) like ''' + upper(@Number) + '%'''

if(@Name<>'')
set @sQuery = @sQuery + 'and upper(ud.FName) like ''' + upper(@Name) + '%'''

Exec(@sQuery )
```

**Note :**

The below given query is just an example i have put off where i am not getting how to handle the if condition in simple query.(Actual query has a lot of things)

**Thanks in advance for any help**

Comment: as i added a note ~ it is just a part of query ~ and its a some part which is inside Store Procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to group each test in a `OR` construct with the parameter being empty (*or whatever check -inverted- you do in the `if`*)..

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    #tb_user ud
WHERE
    (@Number = '' OR upper(ud.ID) like upper(@Number) + '%')
    AND
    (@Name = '' OR upper(ud.FName) like upper(@Name) + '%')
```

*thanks go to @bartosz for spotting an error in the initial answer logic*

Comment: if you pass null parameter to the query you could do something like this WHERE upper(ud.ID) like upper(ISNULL(@Number, ud.ID)) + '%'

Comment: But is this equivalent to the dynamic query? Note that it returns no record if \@Number = '' or \@Name = '', while the dynamic query would simply skip one or both ifs in that case. (See also my answer to this question.)

Comment: @BartoszKlimek, good catch.. you are absolutely right. The `if` needs to be inverted in the sql group.. ***updated answer***

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you only want to use a specific filter (@Number or @Name) if it's not empty:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    #tb_user ud
WHERE
    (@Number = '' OR upper(ud.ID) like upper(@Number) + '%')
    AND
    (@Name = '' OR upper(ud.FName) like upper(@Name) + '%')
```